# Vanishing Fourier transform and bounded functions

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

Let us consider $f$ a function in $C(\mathbb{R})\cap L^{\infty}$ admitting a Fourier transform (say, either in the $L^1$ sense or tempered distribution sense if $f \notin L^1$). We assume that $supp(\hat f)\subset \mathbb{R} \setminus [-1,1]$, that is, if $\hat f$ is a function, $\hat f(\xi)=0$ whenever $|\xi|<1$. Let $u$ be an antiderivative of $f$, i.e. $u'=f$.

> Prove that $u$ is bounded.

Here is how I started: assuming that $\hat f$ is a function we have $\hat u = \frac{i}{\xi}\hat f(\xi)=\frac{i(1-\chi (\xi)}{\xi}\hat f(\xi)$ where $\chi$ is a smooth function compactly supported $\subset [-1,1]$ and $=1$ around $0$. Then we write $u=\phi *f$ where $\phi = (\frac{i(1-\chi(\xi)}{\xi})^\vee$ and by Young we have $\|u\|_{L^{\infty}} \leq \|f\|_{L^{\infty}}\|\phi\|_{L^{1}}$, thus it remains to prove that $\phi \in L^1$. We have $\phi (x)=\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{2\sin (x\xi)}{\xi}d\xi$ and by integration by part we can prove $\phi (x)=O(1)$ at $x=0$ and $\phi(x)=O(1/x^2)$ away from zero, thus the result. Here are two questions:

1. What is the best way to recover the result in full generality?
2. Is there another solution? I feel like there is, since in the $L^1$ case, $u(\infty)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)dx=\hat f(0)=0$, thus antiderivatives are bounded. But how can one pass to the general case?

N.B. The website tells me that the same question already appears [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1604165/fourier-transform-of-a-distribution-null-on-1-1) but the answer given by the OP is not satisfactory, I find it higlhy nonnatural.